# Setting up the get_shorty plugin for bit.ly shortlinks on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, bit.ly

I'm trying to get bit.ly shortlinks to link to one of my model's show pages for Twitter functionality that I want to incorporate into my app.

It seems like the https://github.com/playgood/get_shorty is the best thing I could find out there, but I'm having trouble setting it up.

I think this is where my problem is, but I"m stumped:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

    include GetShorty  
    has_short_url :long_url_host => "localhost:3000" :long_url_method => #What should I put here?
```

The plugin documentation "this would probably be a resourceful route helper method for example page_url"

How would I set that up? Do I include routes.rb into the model and use the helper method?

Answer (score 1):

The plugin didn't mention this `long_url_host` in the README, but try it with the bit.ly api as intended instead.

you should just set up your api_key and credentials in an intitializer and put the `has_short_url` in the model.

Comment: tried it first without the parameters and wasn't able to get any shortlinks from bitly.  Pretty sure I set up the initializer correctly.